# Running register values through translated code. ARM assembly disassembling

Tags: assembly, arm, conceptual

The ARM code I have disassembled is mainly for context, as I'm confused on a more conceptual level. I am given register files in 8 bits

```
R0: 0001 1101
R1: 0000 0111
R2: 0000 0000
R3: 0000 0000
R4: 0000 0000
R5: 0000 0000
R6: 0000 0000
R7: 0001 0000
```

My question is how do I run the above values through the code below? I am confussed mostly on how there seems to be three R values in use, R1, R2, R3(the destination). How would I apply a value such as R4?

My guess is that the 2 four bit values above replace the 2 values in the code table below, but any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
This is a the format of instructions i'm given

bits  |15:14   |13:10   |9|8:6  |5:3  |2:0
field |unused  |opcode  |w|src1 |src2 |dst 

Table I am given is on the left, my disassembly is on the right after -->
Addr|Code
0x00|07 FF --> 0000 0111 1111 1111 --> opcode 0001,dst 111 subtract R1, R2, R3
0x02|06 08 --> 0000 1101 0000 1000 --> opcode 0011,dst 000 shift R1 left 1 bit
0x04|28 08 --> 0010 1000 0000 1000 --> opcode 1010,dst 000 R1 is true R2 False or vice versa
0x06|38 02 --> 0011 1000 0000 0010 --> opcode 1110,dst 010 Jump to addr
0x08|02 47 --> 0000 0010 0100 0111 --> opcode 0000,dst 111 Add R1,R2,R3
0x0A|3C 00 --> 0011 1100 0000 0000 --> opcode 111,dst 000 Halt
```

Comment: The fields of the instruction say which register to use for which operand placeholder.

Comment: Could you give an example of the field of instruction? It's probably simple, I just can't see it.

Comment: Not sure what architecture you use, you say it's ARM but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: Okay, so the first example,  `src1=111`, `src2=111` and `dst=111` meaning it's `SUB R7, R7, R7`

Comment: My guess is there's some confusion between "R1, R2, R3" meaning "the first, second, and third registers of the instruction, whatever they happen to be" vs. those being explicit register names. For example the instruction at address 0x00 does not seem to use R1, R2, R3 as the comment indicates unless the register index encoding is different. (And it would have to vary by slot, which is almost certainly not the case.) As Jester points out, using a direct encoding, it names R7 three times.

Comment: there is too much information missing, this is clearly not arm and/or it is arm (thumb) and you dont have your fields correct.

Comment: using your fields note that there are three bits per to hold the register, and you have 8 registers so unless this is not very sane the bit patter 000 is register 0, 001 is register 1, and so on as Jester said above. your offset 02 instruction has 100 001 000 so r4,r1,r0

Comment: Got it! Thanks all.